# Alternative to CrashPlan

Tags: backup

I use CrashPlan to take frequent backups of my Minecraft server, it's great for getting restores at certain points in time before events have occurred. I only need to backup to a local disk so is there an alternative to this program without paying for online storage?

Comment: Because all of these are ONLINE services with no functionality to automatically backup and restore files from specific times. I don't want to pay for CrashPlan because I don't require CrashPlan Central.

Comment: CrashPlan offers free local disk backup, which is the reason I got confused, thinking you needed cloud backup.

Comment: Installed CrashPlan again and realised why I had to leave it in the first place. Backing up more than once per day is a CrashPlan + feature

Comment: The simple solution is write a simple .bat file that uses SkyDrive, DropBox, Google drive and creates revisions yourself.  Otherwise you can always pay for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

CrashPlan is a free program.
You can [install](http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/download.html) and use it without paying anything.

You only need to pay if you use the CrashPlan Central destination.